# Captcha using mathmatics

Tags: php

I am trying to make a captcha with mathematics, where i took 2 random variable, sum them and match with user input. But when Me/user click on submit button, the value of two variable change and doesn't match with user input. How can i solve this ? any suggestion ?

```
 <?php      
   $a = rand(1,9);
   $b = rand(1,9);
   $z = $a + $b;
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

     $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
       if ($captcha != $z){
         echo $captcha." and ".$z;
        }
        else {
         echo "true";       
        }

     }
   ?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
   <div class="input-group">
     <span><?php echo $a."+".$b."= ?"; ?></span>
     <input type="text" name="captcha">
   </div>
     <button name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Or separate your logic to different files

Comment: Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to store the random numbers you generated for use in subsequent requests by the same user.

Comment: This is a poor CAPTCHA easily defeated by bots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about keeping the correct result you expect to receive in a session variable?
It would be "invisible" to the end user and would allow you to easily cross-check it with the value in `$_POST`.

Here's what I'm thinking:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $a = rand(1,9);
    $b = rand(1,9);
    $z = $a + $b;

    $_SESSION['captcha_result'] = $z;
} else {
    $z = $_SESSION['captcha_result'];
    unset($_SESSION['captcha_result']);

    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

    if ($captcha != $z) {
        echo $captcha . " and " . $z;
    } else {
        echo "true";
    }
    exit; // Don't display the form in case the user is summiting a captcha challenge
}
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
   <div class="input-group">
     <span><?php echo $a."+".$b."= ?"; ?></span>
     <input type="text" name="captcha">
   </div>
     <button name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

You can read more about using sessions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: By the way, this is what sessions where created for in the first place. They are a way to preserve certain data across subsequent accesses. In your case, you do have two subsequent accesses - you are basically doing one request when generating the captcha form and one request when submitting the result and there is no "persistency" between them in the initial code you posted.